# How to set a string from a txt to a variable with cmd

Tags: string, variables, path, cmd, text-files

I have a txt file to a specific path that contains one or more line just like 
the following:

```
Directory of c:\folderA\folderB
Directory of c:\folderC\folderD
```

these are the paths of a program example.exe. I want automatically to find the path that example.exe exists in my computer and to run it from a .cmd script. So far i have succeed to log the paths of existence to a txt. How can I set a variable with only the path of
the first line?

The final result should be `var_path=c:\folderA\folderB`

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is:

```
@echo off
Call :getFirstDirectory
::do your stuff with %var_path%. For example:
@echo %var_path%

exit /b

:getFirstDirectory
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (dirs.txt) do (
set var_path=%%a
exit /b
)
```

Which assumes that `dirs.txt` is the file containing:

```
Directory of c:\folderA\folderB
Directory of c:\folderC\folderD
```